# SPARQL Get names/text instead of identifiers as result

Tags: sparql

I have put together a sparql-query that asks for information about a (music)band. But I only get identifiers(QXXXXX) as results which forces me to create new queries to get names. Is it possible to directly get a name, for example "New York City" for `location_of_formation`, in the query below?

```
  PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
  PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
  SELECT ?location_of_formation
         ?country_of_origin      
         (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?founded_by;separator=", ") AS ?members) 

  WHERE {
       wd:Q124179 wdt:P740 ?location_of_formation .
       wd:Q124179 wdt:P495 ?country_of_origin .
       wd:Q124179 wdt:P112 ?founded_by .
       SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en".  } 
 }
 GROUP BY ?location_of_formation ?country_of_origin
```

Comment: I mean, you copy and pasted the label service into your query, why not using it then: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual#Label_service . Indeed, for `group by` you have to use a subquery when using the label service

Comment: - or just use good old `rdfs:label` property and add the triple patterns to your query - with `filter(lang(?var_of_the_label_here) = 'en')` on the language then?